# How to extract common words from two valiables in core php

Tags: php, arrays, string

```
$a=I love India.
$b=India is my country.
```

in core php how can extract common word from these two variables.

Comment: explode() and array_intersect()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this, the [live demo](https://eval.in/792799)

```
$a='I love India';
$b='India is my country';
print_r(array_intersect(explode(' ', $a), explode(' ', $b)));
```

Comment: it gives following error  "message": "explode() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given",

Comment: you can check it now.

Comment: @KrisRoofe add the [2] to extract the exact the word ?

Comment: @KrisRoofe, I think for exploding text it is better to use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php): `preg_split("/[\s,.!?]+/", "some text here")`, as it takes punctuation marks into account.

Comment: @sevavietl yeah I agree with you.